# How to get a resource String in the c# code in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I followed this tutorial to localize my app:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#Y1210

So I created the class:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        public LocalizedStrings()
        {
        }

        private static Foo.AppResources localizedresources = new Foo.AppResources();

        public Foo.AppResources Localizedresources { get { return localizedresources; } }

    }
}
```

When I use `{Binding Path=Localizedresources.String1, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}` in the XAML files it works great, but

**how can I access to the String1 in the source code** e.g. to set a `textBlock.Text`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C# you can just do:

```
textBlock.Text = AppResources.MyLocalizedString;
```

or in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.MyLocalizedString, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" >
```

Comment: Is there another way to bind the LocalizedResources in C# code?

Comment: @Xander do you have a specific issue with the above? Or are you just curious?

Comment: I am sharing my code in WP8, in my child project I can't use the above piece of code as that would return the parent's values. I want to get the values from child's AppResources.resx file. So if I Bind this value using Binding b = new Binding(); will I be able to achieve that? I have made a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258300/in-shared-classes-how-to-use-local-resources

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the code behind (i.e. c#), use the following to access the APPResources to display your localizedString like this:

busStopAppBtn.Content = AppResources.aBusStopAppBtn;

Obviously, the name of the object (i.e. app button (e.g. BusStopAppBtn)) can be any object of choice while the access modifier is AppResources. followed by the name of the object in your .resx file (i.e. aBusStopAppBtn).

I hope this helps.

I used the article "How to build a localized app for Windows Phone 8" which can be discovered here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)